# How to recover a PowerApp?

Tags: powershell, powerapps

My app is no longer shown listed under `Apps` in the Default environment at `make.powerapps.com`.

When I run `Get-AdminPowerApp` PowerShell cmdlet against the Default env, the App **is** listed.

When I run `Get-AdminDeletedPowerAppsList`, the App **is not** listed.

When I try to run `Set-AdminPowerAppOwner`, I receive an error...

```
Error=; 
Message=No permission to the 'SharepointFormApp' application that has ID = '<guid-here>'.;
Internal=System.Net.HttpWebResponse
```

...but I have permissions on the SharepointList that the App is built on.

How do I troubleshoot and if necessary recover this app?

Comment: did you managed to solve this?

Comment: No. I'm stuck..

Answer (score 1):

Try to go to https://admin.powerplatform.microsoft.com/environments, select the default environment and the Power Apps.
This should give you a complete list of apps in the environment.
I have on a few occations found flows that was disappeared this way.
[image]

Comment: Yeah, I did that. The app is present in the Environment but when I click the three dots next to the app name, all options are greyed out. There is no way to add a new App Owner or Share the app with a Co-Owner. The app is in limbo!

Comment: Are you logged in with the owner account of the app?

Comment: No. I'm an Environment Admin. The owner of the app (the one who can not see the app when going to `make.powerapps.com`) does not have access to `admin.powerplatform.com`.